# Как изменить данные в БД, по событию нажатия на кнопку, и обновить данные на странице?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, backend

Данные вводятся в ячейку таблицы с помощью события JS, в этой же ячейке хранится переменная python  и отображает значение из базы данных, каким образом с помощью нажатия на кнопку изменить значение переменной python.

**html**
[image: фото]

```
  <form action = "", id="zapros2", method = "POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            {% for j in vibor %}
                            <td name="1" style="text-align: center;"  id="theorjs1">{{j.t1_score}}</td>
                            <td  name="2" style="text-align: center;" id="theorjsObsh"  rowspan="3">{{j.t_score}}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 75px;text-align: center"><button style="background-color: white;border: 2px solid black;padding: 5px;", value= "Submit", type="submit">Выбрать</button></td>
                        </form>
```

**views.py**

```
vibor = Cadets.objects.values('t_score','t1_score','t2_score','t3_score').filter(id = pk)
    if request.POST:
        t_score = request.GET["1"]
        print(t_score)
    context = {
           'res': res , 'vibor': vibor 
    }
    return render(request,'main/index2.html', context)
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку - данные можно отправить на сервер запросом... Там их принять и сделать нужные "серверные дела". По окончании дел отправить ответ на запрос. Потом на клиенте обработать тот ответ.

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку данные будут отправляться на сервер с помощью ajax? В идеале мне нужно отправить их в views.py, там принять и отправить в БД

Comment: Можно и форму отправить... Данные так же придут на сервер и после их обработки страница перерисуется с новыми данными. Если перегружать страницу не нужно тогда `ajax`...

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError данная ошибка выходит, если получать данные, как я это делаю в views.py

Comment: Мне просто необходимо с помощью кнопки ввести число(оценка) в ячейку, забрать ее, эту оценку поменять в базе данных и отобразить ее в этой же ячейке

Comment: Тогда отправляй запросом... При получении ответа от сервера что "все хорошо" - меняй что нужно на странице...